# Add an option (starting with a dash) if a boolean is true

Tags: bash

Suppose I have a command:

```
./my_program --option1 --option2 --option3
```

Is there a way to use `--option3` only if a boolean variable is true without writing `./my_program --option1 --option2` more than one time?

---

I tried this:

```
use_option3=1 # or 0

option3=""
if [[ $use_option3 == 1 ]]; then
    option3="--option3"
fi

./my_program --option1 --option2 "$option3"
```

But it doesn't work when `$use_option` is set to `0`, because `./my_program` receives an empty argument (cf. Biffen comment).

Comment: Bash doesn’t have booleans. `true` and `false` are both truthy in `[ $use_option3 ]`. Empty strings are usually used for falsey values, but would break `[ $use_option3 ]` because of a lack of quotes. **EDIT** OK, the latter seems to work, but quoting’s still a good habit.

Comment: …and `"$option3"` will create an empty argument to `my_program` even if the variable is empty.

Comment: @Biffen Regarding booleans, I fixed the script (this is not the real problem, I use integers in my script).

Comment: That’ll work (except it should be just the one `=`, and the variable should be quoted). If you want more help I suggest expanding on the ‘*doesn’t work*’ part; it’s not much to go on.

Comment: @Biffen The problem occurs when the `$option3` variable is empty (probably related with the fact that it creates an empty argument, as you stated). Do you know a way to avoid that?

Comment: Something like `set -- ./my_program --option1 --option2 ; [ "${use_option3:-}" ] && set -- "$@" --option3 ; "$@"` should work. See also: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: @Biffen Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `bash`, the simplest thing to do is collect *all* the arguments you want in a single array.

```
opts=(--option1 --option2)

if [[ $use_option3 == 1 ]]; then
    opts+=(--option3)
fi

./my_program "${opts[@]}"
```

---

A fragile approach could also work. As long as the option contains only alphanumeric characters (a conservative, though reasonable, assumption), you can use the `${var:+word}` expansion operator

```
./my_program --option1 --option2 ${use_option3:+--option3}
```

If `use_option3` has *any* non-empty value, the expansion produces `--option3`. Otherwise, the expansion produces an *unquoted* empty string, which is discarded from the command line.